# Virtual Linux server on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: virtual-machines, windows

I have a dedicated windows 2008 server box, and 3 static Ip set on it.
Can I install a Linux Virtual machine on it my self ? ( I have admin permission )
What software I have to use for virtual server and how can I manage IPs on this server for Windows and Linux ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a dedicated server and not a VM, you can just install the Hyper-v server role and run the Linux VM from there. I run 2 CentOS boxes on Hyper-v without any issues at all. From the experience, Ubuntu, CentOS and Suse/OpenSuse run fine. I haven't played around with any other flavors though.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan said, install Hyper-V as a server role. It runs Linux very well. The only thing I'd like to add is that you'll need to install a 'legacy network adapter' for the virtual machine. I wasted a good chunk of time wondering why I had no network conductivity.

To do this, select your newly created virtual machine in Hyper-V, and select 'Settings'. Then at the top click 'Add Hardware', select 'Legacy Network Adapter' from the list, and click 'Add'. Once this is completed you should be able to configure it as you would a traditional network adapter in Hyper-V.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a software like Vmware Server or Oracle Virtualbox.
About IPs, just use them as you want.

Comment: Please...if you up or down the score, give at least a motivation